# I can't tell what kind of frame I have

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image] can you please let me know what kind of frame I have

Comment: Is it steel or aluminium alloy?  You can tell using a magnet.

Comment: Is there any sort of logo or decal on the other side or on the head tube?

Comment: Do you have any more parts, like the fork and wheels and transmission ?

Comment: You answered so quickly @Criggie, that I didn't have time to respond with my usual: "Black bicycle frame. No markings suggest it might be stolen." type of snarky comment.

Comment: @RoboKaren TBH painted==stolen is more likely if its complete.  Given someone's made the effort to strip it down and paint it nicely/properly then its slightly more likely to be a failed/uncompleted project.   OP: Its worth about 1-5c/kilo as scrap steel, or about $1/kilo for aluminium.  As it is, this is a bike component, not a bike.

Comment: @Criggie -  lol. I'll remember that for next time: "Looks like a black bicycle component. Very don't give valuations but if we did, $0.10 - $3."

Comment: We need a new term: BCSO - bike component shaped object.

Comment: I would say it's "black".  (It's a bit unusual, actually, with the rectangular tubing.  Might even be hand-built.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a BMX or a child's bike - built to be a single-speed because of the horizontal rear dropouts.

The external cups on the headset suggest a newer bike, not a vintage.

The brutish-square box section might help identify it - apparently many companies used square box, more so in the rear.

Example: Redman (as an example of box section in use) [image]

Comment: It's not a Redman. Look at those beautiful welds and tube shaping on the Redman compared to the crap welds on the OP's bike.

Comment: External headset cups are older technology, integrated appeared in the 2000s. This is opposite from bottom brackets.

Comment: @RoboKaren the Redman one was simply an example of box section frames, it was not my intent to suggest that as a brand.   Maybe its a home-made frame?  TBH I can't really see the welds on the original photo.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is a low grade BMX frame designed for 20 inches wheels.
Caliper brake mount time
The picture is not clear but looks like it is a steel frame rather than Alloy one.

Comment: Yes, I don't think you can get quite as ugly welds with aluminium (note that steels and most metals used in bikes are all 'alloys'). Check the rear dropouts. I think they might just be using spot welds!!!!

Answer (score -2):

It kinda looks like a red line triple x think 1997 or so with the square tubing but can't tell for sure

Comment: Got a link or a photo to corroborate your suggestion?

Comment: The rear dropouts seem quite different from the Redline bikes I see on Google.

Answer (score -4):

It's a hawk from the 1990's....

Comment: Welcome to SE - please consider adding some supporting information to corroborate your claim.  Also take a moment to read the [tour] and learn how StackExchange works - its a Q&A site not a common chat forum.  Requests for trades, swaps, buying/selling and valuations are all off topic.

Comment: I'm going to leave this answer in place, and hopefully Jesse will expand it with further info.   Otherwise it could be a lead for OP.  We'll let the votes speak.